# Filing or balancing array with dynamic generated index and values

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

Basically I want to balance an array.

The array I want to balance is retrieved from DB and can be unknown

Here is sample array retrieved from DB, it can vary

```
<?php
$arr_from_DB = array(
            '1'=>NULL,
            '2'=>1,
            '3'=>1,
            ); 

 $node_width_from_DB = 3;
 $node_depth_from_DB = 2;
?>
```

//Max Capacity was caclulated from  $node_width_from_DB, $node_depth_from_DB AND WAS ALSO SAVED in DB , simulated below for width = 3 , depth = 2
 $max_cap_of_array = 13;

//With $arr_from_DB fed to the display fxn on frontend, this is the result 
[image]

//What I want to achieve, I want to transform $arr_from_DB to below ARray, All Array index with negative is seen to be dynamically generated

```
<?php
$formated_arr = array(
            '1'=>NULL,
            '2'=>1,
            '3'=>1,
            '-1'=>1,
            '-2'=>2,
            '-3'=>2,
            '-4'=>2,
            '-5'=>3,
            '-6'=>3,
            '-7'=>3,
            '-8'=>-1,
            '-9'=>-1,
            '-10'=>-1,
            );
?>
```

//With $formated_arr fed to the display fxn on frontend, this is the result 
[image: Matrix Balance]

WHAT I TRIED SO FAR

```
<?php    
$arr_filled = RECfillMissingDownlineArr($arr_from_DB); 


var_dump($arr_filled);

  function RECfillMissingDownlineArr($selectedArr, $pointer=1){

    $node_width_from_DB = 3;
    $node_depth_from_DB = 2;

    //Max Capacity was caclulated from  $node_width_from_DB, $node_depth_from_DB AND WAS ALSO SAVED in DB , simulated below for width = 3 , depth = 2
    $max_cap_of_array = 13; 

    //var_dump($Allarr);
     if($pointer>= $max_cap_of_array){
        return $selectedArr;
     }


    $array_worked = array_count_values($selectedArr);
    $array_worked3 = array_keys($selectedArr);
    $array_worked2 = array_values($array_worked3);


            //$key_p =  $array_worked3[$pointer];


           foreach($array_worked as $key=>$value){

                 //echo 'Value nm'.$value.'<br>';
               if($value<$node_width_from_DB){



                 $key_p =  $key;
                 break;  
               }

           }



           $array_worked1 = array_keys($selectedArr, $key_p);
           for ($i=0; $i <$width ; $i++) {

               if(empty($array_worked1[$i])){
                   $key_pointer = $pointer * -1;
                  $selectedArr[$key_pointer] = $key;

                  $pointer++;

                   return RECfillMissingDownlineArr($selectedArr,$pointer);
               }

             }


     }

OUTPUT NULL, It's not what I want, it's returning null alltogether

?>
```

Comment: Please don't yell.

Comment: What, *exactly*, is your question?

Comment: I want to fill missing array index and values?, I have edited my question pics, please check

Comment: So I can have a transformation from PIC 1 to PICS 2

Comment: @JayBlanchard, have you seen edit?